# Quadratic polynomial satisfied by $\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

**I got one problem from Dummit Foote stating that determine the quadratic polynomial satisfied by the period $\alpha=\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ of the the $5th$ root of unity $\zeta_5$. Determine the quadratic equation satisfied by $\zeta_5$ over $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and use this to explicitly solve for the $5th$ root of unity.**

I am not getting even to find out the quadratic polynomial as $x=\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ iff $x^2=\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^{-2}+2$ not in $\Bbb Q$.
Moreover, if the base field is $\Bbb R$ then $\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ is in  $\Bbb R$. So probably I am not understanding the question correctly. Please help or give me some hints steps..

***Edit*** With the help of the comments

1. "determine the quadratic polynomial satisfied by the period $\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ of the the $5th$ root of unity $\zeta_5$". The answer is $x^2+x-1$.
2. " Determine the quadratic equation satisfied by $\zeta_5$ over $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$". The answer is $x^2-\alpha x +1$

What about the last part? "use this to explicitly solve for the $5th$ root of unity."?

Comment: $1+\zeta + \zeta^2 + \zeta^3 + \zeta^4 = 0.$ Divide by $\zeta^2, $ you get $\zeta^2 + \zeta + 1 + \frac{1}{\zeta} + \frac{1}{\zeta^2} = 0$

Comment: I have solved the first two parts thanks for the help. What is the meaning of the last one?

Comment: what is $\alpha$?

Comment: Sorry I have edited $\alpha=\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$

Comment: Well, now you have a quadratic polynomial of which $\alpha$ is a root, so solve that quadratic equation!

Comment: Which one? the second one? Yes I got it. It should be the 2nd one thanks.. :)

Comment: **Use this to explicitly solve for the 5th root of unity**. I guess that the idea is to   express a primitive 5-th root $\zeta$  of 1 in terms of radicals. The quadratic equation in 2. gives $\zeta=(\alpha \pm \sqrt {\alpha ^2 -1})/2$. The one in 1. gives $\alpha=(-1 \pm \sqrt 5 ) /2$.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2783280/11619) for a bit more general discussion of when and how rewriting everything in terms of the new variable $z=x+1/x$ helps. Summary: Even degree palindromic polynomials in $x$ can be rewritten as a lower degree polynomials in $z$ by utilizing the palindromic symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

You have found that

- $\alpha = \zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ satisfies $x^2+x-1$
- $\zeta_5$ satisfies $x^2-\alpha x+1$

we can solve for $\alpha$ using the quadratic equation: $\alpha = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ (and note $\alpha^2 = \frac{6 - 2 \sqrt{5}}{4} = \frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$)

and similarly we can solve for $\zeta_5 = \frac{\alpha + \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 4}}{2}$

putting these together and finding the right choices of signs we have

$$\zeta_5 = \frac{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \sqrt{-\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}}{2}$$

Comment: we cannot denest the radical $\sqrt(-(5 + \sqrt(5))/2))$