# What does "$\cos(\pi/17)$ is an algebraic number of degree $8$" mean? (Heptadecagon, Wolfram MathWorld)

Tags: geometric-construction

In [Heptadecagon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Heptadecagon.html) page:

> The trigonometric functions $\cos(\pi/17)$ and $\cos(2\pi/17)$ are both algebraic numbers of degree 8 given respectively by:
>
> $\cos(\pi/17) = (256x^8-128x^7-448x^6+192x^5+240x^4-80x^3-40x^2+8x+1)_8\\
> \cos(2\pi/17) = (256x^8+128x^7-448x^6-192x^5+240x^4+80x^3-40x^2-8x+1)_8$

I don't know what *x* is and what the subscript $8$ means.

If it means $256x^8-128x^7-448x^6+192x^5+240x^4-80x^3-40x^2+8x+1=0$, how can we prove that *$x$* is a constructible number?

(I know how to prove $\cos(\pi/17)$'s constructibility which is found [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%81%E4%B8%83%E8%BE%B9%E5%BD%A2#%E8%AD%89%E6%98%8E). But I don't understand the equations mentioned above.)

Comment: It’s a root of that polynomial

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number for a definition

Comment: I'm not *entirely* sure of the subscript notation, but it happens to be true that both $\cos(\pi/17)$ and $\cos(2\pi/17)$ are the *greatest* roots of their respective minimal polynomials, hence in 8th positions when the roots are arranged in order.

Comment: Meanwhile, the whole business is in Galois Theory by Cox. Chapter 9 gives Gauss periods in modern language. Chapter 10 is about constructible numbers. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Galois_Theory/vBKrOch1AkYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: If you want to see that polynomial equation derived, then it follows in a straightforward manner starting from the fact $$2\cos(2\pi/17)=\zeta+\zeta^{-1},$$ where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/17}$ is the prescribed complex root of unity, together with the fact
$$\zeta^8+\zeta^7+\cdots+\zeta+1+\zeta^{-1}+\cdots+\zeta^{-7}+\zeta^{-8}=0$$ that follows from the formula for a geometric sum. [This old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2783305/11619) describes the technique and derives a polynomial equation for the simpler $2\cos(2\pi/5)$ as an example.

Comment: A description of how constructibility follows from using $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ can be found from many textbooks. Such as the one Will Jagy linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscript $8$ is a notation that is used to identify a particular root of the enclosed polynomial.  This is not a commonly used notation, but the ordering is (poorly) documented in *Mathematica*:

> The ordering used by `Root[f,k]` takes real roots to come before complex ones, and takes complex conjugate pairs of roots to be adjacent.

In fact, the ordering is in ascending magnitude of the real-valued roots, followed by ordering the complex-valued roots in a way that is not obvious to me; all I can say is that they are arranged in increasing order of real part, but there does not seem to be a consistent rule for the ordering of roots with the same real part but different imaginary parts.  This is more of a question for Mathematica.SE as it is specific to the implementation in *Mathematica*.  But suffice it to say this is not a standard notation.

In any case, your specific situation is not ambiguous because the roots of the minimal polynomials for $\cos \frac{2\pi}{17}$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{17}$ are all real-valued:  there are no complex-valued roots.  So when the subscript $8$ is used, it is referring to the unique largest real root.

As for $x$, this is just a placeholder variable.  It makes no difference if it is $x$ or $y$ or "ducks."  The point is that there is a polynomial $f$ of degree $8$ of some variable, and the solution of the equation $f = 0$ for that variable leads to $8$ real-valued roots, the largest of which is $\cos \frac{2\pi}{17}$ or $\cos \frac{\pi}{17}$ depending on which polynomial we are talking about.

But you are correct:  just by looking at the polynomial, we cannot immediately tell whether such a polynomial has roots that are constructible--i.e., they are expressible using only a finite number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions and square root operations on integers.